# How to make display second div on second row and other first and third div to display on first row in MUI appbar?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I have 3 parts in appbar,
1. Logo
2. Search Input
3. Login Buttons

For desktop, everything will be in single row like below

[image: AppBar]

Here is my code

```
export default function NavBar(props) {
return (
<>
  <CssBaseline />
  <HideOnScroll {...props}>
    <AppBar elevation={0}>
      <Container sx={{ pl: { xs: '5px', sm: '5px', md: '16px' }, pr: { xs: '5px', sm: '5px', md: '16px' } }}>
        <Toolbar sx={{ pl: { xs: '0px', sm: '0px', md: '16px' }, pr: { xs: '5px', sm: '5px', md: '16px' } }}>
  
          //First Part
          <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 600, display: { xs: 'inline-block', sm: 'inline-block', md: 'inline-block' } }}>LOGO</Typography>
          
          //Second Part
          <InputSearch />

          //Third Part
          <DivRight>
            <IconButton sx={{ color: '#fff' }} size='large' aria-label="add to shopping cart">
              <AddShoppingCartIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Button variant="outlined" size='small' sx={{backgroundColor:'#fff', height:'30px', borderColor:'#fff'}}>Login</Button>
          </DivRight>
  
  </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  </HideOnScroll>
</>
)
}
```

I want to display for the **second part** search Input to be display on second row

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `<Toolbar>` container and style it with flex box and some additional styles. Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-framework-mui-navbar-second-row-kc55it?file=/demo.tsx).

Comment: that's not that i want to achieve. For desktop version, everything should be in one row. for Mobile version- only textbox to be in second row

Comment: @Liamneesan ok, first of all, it would be nice to hear "thank you" or sth that I took time to create a working example, second, you description is not clear at all, even your comment " for Mobile version- only textbox to be in second row", what should it mean exactly, I created an example where textbox (only) is in second row, so is it that, so you can take it as mobile version?